# DMG file editing in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mac, dmg-image

I have a compressed dmg file in Ubuntu. I would like open this file and add 2 files to this system and create the compressed dmg file.

I open to doing the same in Windows if its not possible on Linux.

dmg2img will convert this file to an img file. But I do not know of any utility that converts it back to dmg file.

Answer (score 1):

You can mount it with the command line directly in Linux:

```
mount -t hfs -o loop imagename.dmg /mnt/mymountpoint
```

There is also [**dmgextractor**](http://hem.bredband.net/catacombae/dmgx.html) and [**7-zip**](http://www.7-zip.org/) which will allow you to extract them. I know [**TransMac**](http://www.acutesystems.com/dmg.htm) will allow creation of dmg images on Windows, but it costs a bit. On Linux you can build Apple's `diskdev_cmds` package and use [**this handy script**](http://www.trampolinesystems.com/blog/machines/2008/05/19/creating-dmg-files-without-macos-x/) to make dmg images.

Comment: But the mounted image is only in a read only mode, so you can't modify the dmg file.